# jquery onmouseover child pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery('#content111').hide();
        jQuery('.last').mouseover(function () {
            jQuery('#content111').fadeIn();
        });

        jQuery('#content111').mouseout(function () {
            jQuery('#content111').fadeOut();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The above code child pages fadein but my requirement is child pages mouseover also

Comment: You should probably try to explain a little better, it's hard to understand exactly what is happening, and what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Just add [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
jQuery('#content111').on('mouseout',function(){
    jQuery('#content111').fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Actually, you should use `.on()`. The `.live()`-method is depricated in jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Note that the usage of `.live` is deprecated. You should use `.on` for recent versions of JQuery, or `.delegate` for older ones.

Comment: .live() is deprecated! And why would it help? Where exactly in the question does it say the elements are insterted dynamically?

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#content111').hide();
    jQuery('.last').mouseover(function() {
        jQuery('#content111').fadeIn();
    });

    jQuery('#content111').live('mouseout',function(){
        jQuery('#content111').fadeOut();
    });
});`  i tried this its not effecting...child pages fading in i dont want fade in for at the time mouseover on child pages...

Comment: @user1135693 try using .on instead of .live

Comment: ya i used .on its working but another problem is if i mouseout after mouseover it has to fadeout...But its not effecting...can any one help in this regard  thanks for early reply to all

Comment: Well, the answer seems to have changed, but now it's not a delegated event handler, so it's really nothing like .live(), and will not affect dynamic content anyway, so if that works the elements are not dynamic, and the OP did something else wrong. Seeing the HTML structure would probably help in understanding the question?

Comment: hi adeno, check this link[http://javascript-array.com/scripts/jquery_simple_drop_down_menu/] like this i am doing for two divs... any help regarding this...